# Data Cleaning: Counting the number of male actors in Python

Tags: python, pandas

My main data frame looks like this
[image]

Below is what the entirety of a cell in 'cast' column looks like. Trying to identify how many male actors are in 1 film Id.

```
[{'cast_id': 9, 'character': 'Count Dracula', 'credit_id': '52fe44b79251416c7503e811', 'gender': 2, 'id': 7633, 'name': 'Leslie Nielsen', 'order': 0, 'profile_path': '/cZpuTfE1j63tCEXoSL2A7KZjk5d.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 10, 'character': 'Prof. Abraham Van Helsing', 'credit_id': '52fe44b79251416c7503e815', 'gender': 2, 'id': 14639, 'name': 'Mel Brooks', 'order': 1, 'profile_path': '/ndFo3LOYNCUghQTK833N1Wtuynr.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 11, 'character': 'Mina Seward', 'credit_id': '52fe44b79251416c7503e819', 'gender': 1, 'id': 1219, 'name': 'Amy Yasbeck', 'order': 2, 'profile_path': '/c7WOXDlKE9cwTBjpUtCKFPqnptr.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 12, 'character': 'Thomas Renfield', 'credit_id': '52fe44b79251416c7503e81d', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12688, 'name': 'Peter MacNicol', 'order': 3, 'profile_path': '/hw4KTj66xh2FupS5sQMeNMNL6lx.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 13, 'character': 'Lucy Westenra', 'credit_id': '52fe44b79251416c7503e821', 'gender': 1, 'id': 12812, 'name': 'Lysette Anthony', 'order': 4, 'profile_path': '/yLTijECWVviLdhB03IYkZSJJLcY.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 14, 'character': 'Dr. Jack Seward', 'credit_id': '52fe44b79251416c7503e825', 'gender': 2, 'id': 13640, 'name': 'Harvey Korman', 'order': 5, 'profile_path': '/zXLYvJP3ReKPI6lJr2VuDGupL1j.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 15, 'character': 'Jonathan Harker', 'credit_id': '52fe44b79251416c7503e829', 'gender': 2, 'id': 6106, 'name': 'Steven Weber', 'order': 6, 'profile_path': '/ujINzDjLNtELBSUkRHQgExzP4Fb.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 17, 'character': 'Martin', 'credit_id': '52fe44b79251416c7503e833', 'gender': 2, 'id': 29709, 'name': 'Mark Blankfield', 'order': 7, 'profile_path': '/oAtZrKAA1c8XJLBBfW1oXYYt8jS.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 18, 'character': 'Essie', 'credit_id': '52fe44b79251416c7503e837', 'gender': 1, 'id': 53570, 'name': 'Megan Cavanagh', 'order': 8, 'profile_path': '/xZML4JXgD7Yd0f19hXhq7bXLXfC.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 19, 'character': 'Woodbridge', 'credit_id': '52fe44b79251416c7503e83b', 'gender': 2, 'id': 170185, 'name': 'Gregg Binkley', 'order': 9, 'profile_path': '/gTmsOFfFqHDcEzeqh3ezcSuk7TB.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 20, 'character': 'Madame Ouspenskaya', 'credit_id': '56fc3c8dc3a36808a70033f6', 'gender': 1, 'id': 10774, 'name': 'Anne Bancroft', 'order': 10, 'profile_path': '/4VMhut6tvXqXBmMGFRjXbbImAZW.jpg'}]
```

Comment: Can you show the entirety of the contents of the cell? Is it a string or a list?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `df` being your DataFrame can you provide the output of `df.head().to_dict()` as edit of your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [df.value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to get counts of unique values and filter out value 2 using `df.value_counts()[2]`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'cast_id': 9, 'character': 'Count Dracula', 'credit_id': '52fe44b79251416c7503e811', 'gender': 2, 'id': 7633, 'name': 'Leslie Nielsen', 'order': 0, 'profile_path': '/cZpuTfE1j63tCEXoSL2A7KZjk5d.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 10, 'character': 'Prof. Abraham Van Helsing', 'credit_id': '52fe44b79251416c7503e815', 'gender': 2, 'id': 14639, 'name': 'Mel Brooks', 'order': 1, 'profile_path': '/ndFo3LOYNCUghQTK833N1Wtuynr.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 11, 'character': 'Mina Seward', 'credit_id': '52fe44b79251416c7503e819', 'gender': 1, 'id': 1219, 'name': 'Amy Yasbeck', 'order': 2, 'profile_path': '/c7WOXDlKE9cwTBjpUtCKFPqnptr.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 12, 'character': 'Thomas Renfield', 'credit_id': '52fe44b79251416c7503e81d', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12688, 'name': 'Peter MacNicol', 'order': 3, 'profile_path': '/hw4KTj66xh2FupS5sQMeNMNL6lx.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 13, 'character': 'Lucy Westenra', 'credit_id': '52fe44b79251416c7503e821', 'gender': 1, 'id': 12812, 'name': 'Lysette Anthony', 'order': 4, 'profile_path': '/yLTijECWVviLdhB03IYkZSJJLcY.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 14, 'character': 'Dr. Jack Seward', 'credit_id': '52fe44b79251416c7503e825', 'gender': 2, 'id': 13640, 'name': 'Harvey Korman', 'order': 5, 'profile_path': '/zXLYvJP3ReKPI6lJr2VuDGupL1j.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 15, 'character': 'Jonathan Harker', 'credit_id': '52fe44b79251416c7503e829', 'gender': 2, 'id': 6106, 'name': 'Steven Weber', 'order': 6, 'profile_path': '/ujINzDjLNtELBSUkRHQgExzP4Fb.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 17, 'character': 'Martin', 'credit_id': '52fe44b79251416c7503e833', 'gender': 2, 'id': 29709, 'name': 'Mark Blankfield', 'order': 7, 'profile_path': '/oAtZrKAA1c8XJLBBfW1oXYYt8jS.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 18, 'character': 'Essie', 'credit_id': '52fe44b79251416c7503e837', 'gender': 1, 'id': 53570, 'name': 'Megan Cavanagh', 'order': 8, 'profile_path': '/xZML4JXgD7Yd0f19hXhq7bXLXfC.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 19, 'character': 'Woodbridge', 'credit_id': '52fe44b79251416c7503e83b', 'gender': 2, 'id': 170185, 'name': 'Gregg Binkley', 'order': 9, 'profile_path': '/gTmsOFfFqHDcEzeqh3ezcSuk7TB.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 20, 'character': 'Madame Ouspenskaya', 'credit_id': '56fc3c8dc3a36808a70033f6', 'gender': 1, 'id': 10774, 'name': 'Anne Bancroft', 'order': 10, 'profile_path': '/4VMhut6tvXqXBmMGFRjXbbImAZW.jpg'}])
df['gender'].value_counts()[2]
```

Edit: If the cast is stored in a single pandas column, you can use df.apply method to go to each cast list to calculate the number of male cast per film and store in a new column (`'male_count'` in the example below). You can change the `data` variable to be the name of the variable that has the dataframe

```
data['male_count'] = data.apply(lambda x: len([cast['gender'] for cast in x[0] if cast['gender'] == 2]), axis=1)
```

Comment: tried this and it doesnt work maybe because the column title is "cast" not exactly gender?

Comment: @jaz Could you also share the data structure of pandas? It seems to work for me if I use `pd.DataFrame(<data>)` where `<data>` is the data you posted in your above question

Comment: @jaz Also does `df['gender'].value_counts()[2]` return any error message?

Comment: for a single data it works but <data> is just one cell of a column, have any idea how to loop it through all the cells on the column and store the count in a column?

Comment: @jaz So the data would be some thing like `data = [pd.DataFrame([{'cast_id': 9, 'character': 'Count Dracula', 'credit_id': '52fe44b79251416c7503e811', 'gender': 2, 'id': 7633, 'name': 'Leslie Nielsen', 'order': 0, 'profile_path': '/cZpuTfE1j63tCEXoSL2A7KZjk5d.jpg'}]),
  pd.DataFrame([{'cast_id': 10, 'character': 'Prof. Abraham Van Helsing', 'credit_id': '52fe44b79251416c7503e815', 'gender': 2, 'id': 14639, 'name': 'Mel Brooks', 'order': 1, 'profile_path': '/ndFo3LOYNCUghQTK833N1Wtuynr.jpg'}])]` ?

Comment: @jaz Oh I see, I've edited my answer to create a new row that store the number of male casts per film. Let me know if this is the expected result